# Only numeric text input without Regex

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a project from my class and I have to make a postal code form with the input type is text.

html:

```
<label for="postal">Postal Code</label><br>
<input type="text" id="postal"><br><br>
```

And I have to do it only numeric without using regular expression.

Can anyone help with the javascript validation?

Thanks!

Comment: probably no way without regex or mask. But note that international zip codes may be Alphanumeric postal codes also (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_code)

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number):

```
<form validate="validate">
    <label for="tentacles">Number of tentacles (10-100):</label>
    <input type="number" id="tentacles" name="tentacles"
       min="100000" max="999999">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: it doesnt fit because you can enter '-'

Comment: How does increasing the range change the set of valid input characters?

Answer (score 0):

```
const element = documnet.getElementById('postal');
const { value } = element;

const isNumber = !Number.isNaN(+value);
```